# Package org.slf4j is not found gradle

Tags: gradle

When I tried adding these below, into my dependencies I receive an error saying "could not find method compile<> for arguments [log4j:log etc....]

```
compile 'log4j:log4j:1.2.17'
compile 'org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.7.5'
compile 'org.slf4j:slf4j-log4j12:1.7.5'
```

**script**

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'net.saliman:gradle-cobertura-plugin:2.3.1'
    }
}
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}
configurations {
    junitAnt
}
dependencies {
    compile 'log4j:log4j:1.2.17'
    compile 'org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.7.5'
    compile 'org.slf4j:slf4j-log4j12:1.7.5'
    junitAnt 'junit:junit:4.8.2'
    junitAnt('org.apache.ant:ant-junit:1.9.2') {
        transitive = false
    }
    junitAnt('org.apache.ant:ant-junit4:1.9.2') {
        transitive = false
    }
}

apply plugin: net.saliman.gradle.plugin.cobertura.CoberturaPlugin
apply plugin: 'java'
version = 1.0
apply plugin: 'war'

sourceSets {
    main {
        java { srcDir 'src' }
        resources { srcDir 'src' }
        resources { srcDir 'WebContent/WEB-INF/lib' }
    }

    test {
        resources { srcDir 'test' }
    }
}
```

Comment: Where did you add those lines? Show us the complete build file. They must be inside the dependencies closure.

Comment: added the requested script

Comment: What produces the error? What are you doing to get it?

Comment: I am trying to build gradle. After I wrote my source set it is pulling all my imports from my java file and throwing me errors for each import.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Move this section :

```
apply plugin: net.saliman.gradle.plugin.cobertura.CoberturaPlugin
apply plugin: 'java'
version = 1.0
apply plugin: 'war'
```

At the beginning of your `build.gradle`.